# how to use console.log in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console.log

Am new to react, I have a fetch operation and I want to check data from api using console.log before using it just like in javascript but i can't figure out how to do it in react...Any help?

```
const [all, setAll]=React.useState([])

React.useEffect(()=>{ 
    fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=key')
    .then(data=>{
       return data.json()
    }).then(completedata=>{
       setAll(completedata)

    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
        
      })
    
},[1])
console.log(all)
```

Comment: one thing to add also when I did this setAll(completedata) my app wasn't workking but when I  setAll(movies.results) from @Pyjcoder answer below the data was rendered..i don't know why but it works so....Am using TMDB Api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react';

const [all, setAll] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{ 
  fetDataFromApi()
},[]);


const fetDataFromApi = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=key')
      const movies = data.json();
      if(movies.error){
         console.log('error -> ',movies.error)
      else{
        setAll(movies.results)
    }
  }
}

return(
<>
{JSON.stringify(all)}
</>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all still Javascipt, use `console.log(data.results)` in the promise chain, or the `all` state in an `useEffect` hook with dependency on the `all` state.

```
const [all, setAll] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => { 
  fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=key')
    .then(data => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      setAll(data.results);
      console.log(data.results);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
},[]);
```

or

```
const [all, setAll] = React.useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(all);
}, [all]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like as in  javascript:

```
}).then(completedata=>{
   setAll(completedata)
console.log("your complete data is here"+JSON.stringify(completedata))

})
```